# Where can i find the $scripts?

Tags: php, drupal-7

```
<?php print $scripts ?>
```

I've spending several minutes looking the $scripts. I have no success. This is in drupal.

Comment: Not enough information at all, what file did you copy that line from? but try looking at this, https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_process_html/7 , maybe it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its in your respective theme's `.info` file.

Scripts are added like:

```
scripts[] = foo.js
```

Scripts can also be added through programming like:

[drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)

Hope, its enough for you.